# AngularJS directive to validate input text

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a textbox in html form. I want to create a directive in AngularJS which will accept numbers, For example `100` and validate the text field with only numbers and multiple of the passed number which is `100` here.

Comment: And what did you tried so far?

Comment: Currently my input box is like this <input type="text" validate_Invest_amt multiple_val="100" class="form-control" data-ng-model="item.InvestAmt" /> where "validate_Invest_amt" will be the directive name 'multiple_val="100"' will be the attribute value to be passed. How to create the directive

Comment: You can use ng-pattern

Comment: but this value will be dynamic

Comment: You can create your own regex as per your requirement and apply that to ng-pattern.